# Getting balance of my address connecting to a remote node via RPC API?

Tags: monerod, rpc, monero-wallet-rpc

I'm looking to build a Monero web wallet, but I'm not sure how to go about querying the remote Monero nodes to get an updated balance of an address. Let's say I have the Monero private keys, how do I get the balance from a remote RPC API Monero node? What is the API call I need to make? Is there an example of how this is done?

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to use the `monero-wallet-rpc`. Documentation for the API methods are [here](https://getmonero.org/resources/developer-guides/wallet-rpc.html).

Note, this is a different application than the main Monero daemon `monerod`.

UPDATE based on comments:

If you don't want to work with wallet files you will need to implement something like [this](https://github.com/monero-project/monero/blob/3a373c3d3ae9837b4002247f25efcb6325950dd4/src/wallet/wallet2.cpp#L7049). You'll see it invokes a daemon RPC method `/get_address_info` with parameters `address` and `view_key`.

Comment: which of those api calls do I pass my private key to do a rescan to get a balance?

Comment: You would store the wallet on the same machine as the RPC and call open_wallet the getbalance

Comment: I don't want to store my wallet on the same machine. I want to make something like mymonero web wallet where I can just get the balance of a private key. Say I have 100 users on my web application and each one has their own monero private key. How would I update the balance for each of these users? What is the RPC api call where I can pass in the private key to do a scan to get the total balance like how monero mobile wallets do it now.

Comment: If you are going to hold their private keys why not the wallet?

Comment: their private keys will be generated on their local device...

Comment: OK if you don't want to work with wallet files you will need to implement something like [this](https://github.com/monero-project/monero/blob/3a373c3d3ae9837b4002247f25efcb6325950dd4/src/wallet/wallet2.cpp#L7049). You'll see it invokes a daemon RPC method `/get_address_info` with parameters `address` and `view_key`.

Comment: " which of those api calls do I pass my private key to do a rescan to get a balance? " You don't...that's the whole point of having separate node and wallet. You either get the txes from the node and scan, or use something like the mymonero server, with which you can do that (but you leak your secret view key to it).